# Ajaxcontrolkit Input Button does not work after deploy

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, button, ajaxcontroltoolkit

My 3D-AR button does not work after deploy my codes.It need to open new url according to my chechboxs. It works on my local 127.0.0.1:5500. But after deploy my pages via Netlify it is not working. It is working on Snipped. So what could be problem with this ?

Demo Link
https://vigilant-allen-a37d54.netlify.app/

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"][id^="cb"] {
    display: none;
  }
  
  label {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    
    
  }

  .container {

 

    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #707070;

    

  }

  input:focus,
  select:focus,
  textarea:focus,
  button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

  .button {
    background-color:  #4b4b4b;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 62px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
   
    margin: 4px 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 1px solid #4b4b4b;
      border-radius: 16px;
  }

  .button1:hover {
    background-color: #757575;
    color: white;
  }


  
  label::before {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  
  label img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  }
  
  :checked+label {
    border-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  :checked+label::before {
    content: "✓";
    background-color: grey;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  :checked+label img {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
    z-index: -1;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
 
    <title>Dc Works Demo</title>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

 $(function () {
   
    var url = "https://vigilant-allen-a37d54.netlify.app/";

    var choice = [];

    $("input:button[value='3D-AR']").click(function () {
 
        $("input:checkbox[name^='choice']:checked").each(function (i, el) {
  
            choice += "choice=" + $(el).attr('name') + "&";
        });
      
        choice = choice.slice(0, -1);
      
        $('form').attr("action", url + choice).submit();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<br><br><br>
    <div class="container">
    <ul>
        <center><h1>Evinde İstediğin Eşyaları Seç</h1></center>
        <center>
            <br><br>
        <form name="search_something" action="" method="post">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="choice1" id="cb1" />
            
          <label for="cb1"><img src="koltuk.png" /></label>
          <center><p>Gri İkili Koltuk</p></center>
        </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="choice2" id="cb2" />
          <label for="cb2"><img src="dolap.png" /> </label>
          <center><p>Meşe Kahve Dolap</p></center>
        </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="choice3" id="cb3" />
          <label for="cb3"><img src="masa.png" /></label>
          <center><p>Çalışma Masası</p></center>
        </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="choice4" id="cb4" />
          <label for="cb4"><img src="raf.png" /></label>
          <center><p>4lü Raf Sistemi</p></center>
        </li>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <input class="button button1" type="button" value="3D-AR">
    </form>
</center>
      </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Step 1. Open your browser's developer console. Step 2. See the error. Step 3. Fix it. Step 4. Profit. _(you included the jQuery library with `http` instead of `https`)_

Comment: Oh cool! Thank you for responding. It worked. If you dont mind I have another problem. When you choose first option on my demo (I shared link) and click 3D-AR, new page is opening. It says page not found but when we reload page, It loads. What is problem here ? Thanks...

Comment: Replace `method="post"` with `method="get"` in your form's HTML